# How to load objects from sql queries in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: sql, database, joomla2.5

Using the Andrew Eddie's tutorials [here](http://www.theartofjoomla.com/home/9-developer/135-database-upgrades-in-joomla-16.html) I am working on building some custom code for menus. Here we go:

```
$query ->select('id, menutype, title')
       ->from('#__menu_types')
       ->where('menutype='.$somemenu);
    $db->setQuery($query);
```

I don't know how to load one object value like I used to do it with Joomla 1.5:

```
$result = $db->loadObject();
$thetitle = $result->title; // I need this value and I always get error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" at this line
```

How can I SUCCESSFULLY get the value of $thetitle please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct query is

```
$query ->select('id, menutype, title')
       ->from('#__menu_types')
       ->where('menutype='.$db->quote($somemenu));
    $db->setQuery($query);
```

Now I can get the values of the query correctly.

Answer (score 1):

That should work. I see no problem with your code.

The error you are getting is consistent with not having found a match in the database.

Since you do not appear to have any error handling it might even be an SQL error.

Try and add this:

```
if ($error = $db->getErrorMsg()) {
    throw new Exception($error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for input Soren, unforts, I am still unable to get this damn value. It's empty but it's not really empty. That menu_type exists and also has a title.

Comment: Try and add a echo $db->getQuery(); and also a var_dump or print_r on $result after loading

Comment: Same issue
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in some file on same line

here is the echo and the var_dump
SELECT id, menutype, title FROM #__menu_types WHERE menutype=mainmenu
NULL